# How do I rearrange the order of keyframes in my animation?

Tags: animation, keyframes

I have a 3D model that I exported from the source with two animation clips.  In Noesis, I was able to combine the two animation clips into one seamless, looping animation. The problem is that the two clips are in the wrong order.

The full sequence is 697 frames long.  The first clip is named "transform_to_alt_hero" and is 321 frames long.  The second clip is named "transform_to_main_hero" and is 376 frames long.  When I import this FBX into Blender, it plays the second clip, then the first clip.  I need to swap those around so the result will be consistent with other files I've processed in this way.  How can I fix this?

Comment: You should be able to just box select the keyframes in the timeline and drag them around?